# Error in Nokia In- App purchase for Android -"Something went wrong with your Payment"

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, nokia, nokiax

I am trying to implement **"Nokia In- App purchase"** in my android application.

I referred the sample project**"Sample pepper firm"** provided by Nokia.

When I enter a product-id and click on "Buy" button it gives error "Something went wrong with your payment"

I also attached one screen shot of error also.

Please help me to get out of this,I went through nokia's developer site but get confused.

Screen Shot of Error 
[image]

Comment: I suppose we talked this story on the other discussion forum. And the name you were using for the device might indicate that you might be using non sales version device, probably with non-sales version of software, thus you need to contact the party that gave you access to the device and ask for assistance.

Comment: @Dr.Jukka Hey thanks for reply but when I went through "developer.nokia.com" they also suggest to post the question on "Stackoverflow" with tag "nokiax" as I did. If you know any other discussion forum regarding this issue then please tell me about that.

Comment: ok, then it was other person with similar issue, anyways, I would recomnend seeing that the firmware is uptodate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not seem to have any network connectivity at the moment. Wifi is not connected (missing Wifi icon) and you do not have any SIM card inserted (two red lines).

Comment: SIM card is inserted that's why it shows 1 at sim1. But when there is a range it shows same error.

Comment: Oops, sorry. You are right, SIM card is indeed inserted. But you still do not have connectivity for some reason (that red line). Make sure your mobile data works, or connect to Wifi. You can see from the screenshot that your device "can't connect to Store at the moment".

Comment: Thanks for reply..but SIM card is working in other devices. When we insert SIM into device "Norman D" range comes for a very short time but red line is still there, and then range automatically gone..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error. This error came just because there was problem with my device which is not released yet. So its not able to connect SIM card data and internet also.

When I replaced my demo device with "Nokia X" it working for me.